# QGIS API Label expression for vector layer

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, qgis-3

I'm using QGIS 3.3 C++ API (python dev should be able to answer too as both C++ and Python API share the same elements names)

I'm trying to display a label on each point of the layer with this expression :

```
"'L: ' || \"Ref_track\" || ', PK: ' || \"PK\""
```

This expression works in QGIS 3.3 as

```
'L: ' || "Ref_track" || ', PK: ' || "PK"
```

I just adapted it for C++ string writting

here is how i'm doing it :

```
QgsPalLayerSettings mySettings;
QgsExpression myexp("'L: ' || \"Ref_track\" || ', PK: ' || \"PK\"");
mySettings.fieldName = myexp;

QgsTextFormat txtf;
txtf.setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes::RenderPixels);
txtf.setSize(20);
txtf.setColor("#ffffff");
mySettings.setFormat(txtf);


QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling* simpleL= new QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(mySettings);

myPointsVectorLayer->setLabeling(simpleL);
myPointsVectorLayer->setLabelsEnabled(true);
myPointsVectorLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling/isExpression", true);

// commit changes
myPointsVectorLayer->commitChanges();

myPointsVectorLayer->updateExtents();
myPointsVectorLayer->triggerRepaint();
```

When i'm replacing my expression by `"Ref_track"` it works, but by `"\"Ref_track\""` it doesn't ... WHY ?

Comment: How does it not work? Do you receive an error or are the labels not showing?

Comment: no labels showing up, and "isExpression" stay false